# I need to write a shell script to make files executable by default if the file name does not contain system program names like "ls" and "grep"

Tags: linux, shell

**xprog (program name)**
Checks if this is a suitable name for a program, and if so, launches editor and makes sure file is executable by default.

**don't allow use of system program names like "ls"
use "which" to see if command exists
check return code "$?"
touch (program)
make new prog executable
launch editor**

Testing

xprog grep - rejected
xprog newprog - ok, created, is executable, editor launched

I'm really new to shell scripting and any help would be really appreciated, if I get my entire answer then great but any suggestions would help me out greatly. I've been searching for an answer for about 2 hours now and unfortunately I can't seem to find the place to start. The above are the guidelines for me to follow, I understand the what the description is I just can't seem to find the way to implement it on a shell script.  Thanks guys.

Comment: That bolded sentence (homework hint?) pretty much tells you everything you have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

for i; do
    type &>/dev/null "$i" || { chmod +x "$i"; $EDITOR "$i"; }
done
```

Homework/noob version :

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $@; do
    if which &>/dev/null "$i"; then
        true
    else
        chmod +x "$i"
        $EDITOR
    fi
done
```

Total noob version :

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $@; do
    which &>/dev/null "$i"
    if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
        chmod +x "$i"
        $EDITOR
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Test `which`, check return code (implicit in the `if`), touch, make executable, launch editor.

```
if which $1 > /dev/null; then
    echo "rejected"
    exit 1
else
    touch $1
    chmod +x $1
    ${EDITOR} $1
fi
```